# Detect orientation change in Ionic App

Tags: ionic-framework, orientation, detect

I've tried with events, but that doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener('onorientationchange', function() 
   {...}
);
```

I know how to get the orientation of the screen, but i didn't find out how to detect when the orientation changes.

Comment: I realize this question is a little old, but as I was directed here from Google when searching "detect screen orientation change in Ionic" I figured a proper answer might benefit others as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install the `cordova-plugin-screen-orientation` plugin:

For cordova < 4 run:

`cordova plugin add net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation`

For cordova > 4 run:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation`

The plugin adds the following to the screen object (window.screen):

```
// lock the device orientation
.lockOrientation('portrait')

// unlock the orientation
.unlockOrientation()

// current orientation
.orientation
```

Now you can use something like the following to detect the orientation of the screen:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(){
    console.log(screen.orientation); // e.g. portrait
});
```

See https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation for more information/documentation

Answer (score 7):

Pleas try this one:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    ...
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
      console.log(window.orientation);
    }, false);  
  });
})
```

Comment: Should i put this listener in Ready() or Load?

Comment: I've try your code but nothing appears in the console. :/